# Jquery UI .draggable and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I was playing with JqueryUI and I encountered this issue when opening the page in chrome.

Here is the HTML for the page

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jqui">
                <div class="contentTitle">
                    <h1>Playground</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content colored">1                            
                    </div>
                    <div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content colored">2                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="dragcontainer">
                        <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content colored">3
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div><!--jqui End-->  
        </div><!--Container End-->                      
    </div><!--Main End-->
```

You can find the Complete code [here](http://codepen.io/SurajVerma/pen/fxKcD)

In Firefox the draggable box in the pink background container is working all fine but when I am opening in Chrome, it is dragging only upside down and it seems it is taking width of the box as the width of the container.. Am I doing anything wrong here ? I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dragcontainer">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
        <div id="draggable2" style="position:relative;left: -50%;" class="ui-widget-content colored">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    $("#draggable1").draggable({
        revert: true
    });
    $("#draggable2").draggable({
        containment: ".dragcontainer",
        revert: true
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/dz96r7n4/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your response but the problem is as it is if you check it in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Suraj Verma, ok see my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried it that way earlier also, I want it to be aligned center only, as it is working in Firefox, it should work fine in Chrome also, I appreciate if you can suggest me, if I am missing something.

Comment: There is an edited css for your bug.Draggable: draggable can be pulled out of containment in Chrome and IE8 http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7016

Answer (score -1):

I have modified the code as below and it worked in chrome :

```
$(function(){

    $("#draggable").draggable();

    $("#draggable1").draggable({revert:true});

    $("#draggable2").draggable({revert:true});

});
```

Why exactly do you want to add `containment:".dragcontainer"` ?

Comment: Yes, In that way it will work fine, I want it to be draggable inside the container only. Here is the reference link to the JqueryUI page about what I am trying to do. :http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement